# Fatal error: Call to a member function save() on a non-object cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, save

I'm new to cakephp, so I got this error message:

http://imageshack.com/a/img716/3163/ofvq.png

this is my CalaboradoresController.php file:

```
<?php

class ColaboradoresController extends AppController{

    public $name = 'Colaboradores';

    public function add(){
        if($this->data){
            if($this->Colaborador->save($this->data))
                $this->Session->setFlash ('Colaborador adicionado com sucesso!');
        }
    }

}

?>
```

And this is my Colaborador.php file:

```
<?php

    class Colaborador extends AppModel{

        public $name = 'Colaborador';

    }

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried customizing the inflector? I'd guess the default expects `ColaboradorsController`.

Comment: I could try it, but you have to specify how to do that because I'm newbie at cake sorry..

Answer (score 1):

Change you controller filename to ColaboradorsController.php and controller name ColaboradorsController

Or you could just add this to you controller:

```
public $uses = 'Colaborador';
```

Answer (score 1):

Model must have a class name e.g. admin
and the var `$name` initialized will be your table

so when your trying to save data you must refer the model name to `$this->admin->save($this->data)`.

This will save from error

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the Model first before calling the save function.

you can load the Model in 2 ways

First : Define $uses inside your controller you need to explicitly load the Colaborador model:

```
 var $uses = array('Colaborador','MonthlyReturn','Employee','Company');
```

Second : You can use loadModel function like this

```
 $this->loadModel('Colaborador');
```

Use this loadModel function before save function.

I hope this will be helpful for you.